# PHP "use" statement throwing errors when multiple scripts are run

Tags: php, facebook

Related question: [PHP - execute web script as command line script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24337132/php-execute-web-script-as-command-line-script)

So I've got a script, we'll call it MainScript.php, that does the following:

1. Include another script I've made, OtherScript.php, and also the facebook SDK scripts.
2. Ask the user for input. It uses a function in OtherScript.php to help with this, because OtherScript.php is a facebook app script that I've written, and MainScript.php is the front-end of the script. OtherScript.php's function generates the login URL for the user.
3. Upon receiving input, MainScript.php uses shell_exec() to start a background process, to start processing data based on the user's input. The process that's started is ThirdScript.php, which hands off data to OtherScript.php to be processed, and then writes the result to a file that the user can access.

The reason I must do all this is because if I just had MainScript.php process the data, or run OtherScript.php as a child process to process the data, it would be unavailable on my server for other users to access; it would be busy processing data. I need it to process data but remain available for other users. To that end, I have it spawn a new process for each time a user accesses and enters data into MainScript.php, so that it remains available, and the user's data is processed swiftly.

However, the error I get is most odd; when MainScript.php uses shell_exec() to start ThirdScript.php, and then refreshes the page to say "your data is processing" or something to the user, MainScript.php throws the following error:

PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING or '(' in /home7/fantatv1/public_html/MainScript.php on line 6

Line 6 is:

use Facebook\FacebookSession;

I'm not sure what the problem is, because when I run ThirdScript.php directly from the command line, and simply hardcode some arguments into it (to simulate the data gathered from the user from MainScript.php), it runs just fine. No errors.

However, I have a theory that since MainScript.php is "use"ing namespaces, and then OtherScript is also using them, and MainScript.php refreshes itself when the user enters data into the form on the page, there's some problem with calling "use" on a namespace that's already being "use"d. This is just an idea, but I have no idea what the actual problem is. Can anyone give me some advice or help?

MainScript.php:

```
<?php

session_start();
require_once ('otherevent.php');

use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\FacebookResponse;
use Facebook\FacebookSDKException;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
use Facebook\FacebookServerException;
use Facebook\FacebookOtherException;
use Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException;
use Facebook\GraphObject;
use Facebook\GraphSessionInfo;
use Facebook\GraphUser;



$display_login = 0;
$display_logout = 0;


if ( isset( $_SESSION ) && isset( $_SESSION['fb_token'] )) {
  // create new session from saved access_token
  $session = new FacebookSession( $_SESSION['fb_token'] );

  // validate the access_token to make sure it's still valid
  try {
    if ( !$session->validate() ) {
      $session = null;
      $display_login = 1;
    }else{
    $display_logout = 1;
    }
  } catch ( Exception $e ) {
    // catch any exceptions
    $session = null;
    $display_login = 1;
  }

} else {
  // no session exists

  try {
    $session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();
    if(isset($session)){
    if ( !$session->validate() ) {
      $session = null;
      $display_login = 1;
    }else{
    $display_logout = 1;
    }
    }else{
      $display_login = 1;
    }
  } catch( FacebookRequestException $ex ) {
  echo'<p>There was a problem with your facebook session. Please re-login to Facebook, and then try loading the app again.</p>';
    //echo $ex;
    // When Facebook returns an error
  } catch( Exception $ex ) {
  echo'<p>There was a validation issue with your previous session. Please log in again.</p>';
    // When validation fails or other local issues
    //echo $ex;
  }

}

if(isset($session)){
  $_SESSION['fb_token'] = $session->getToken();
  // create a session using saved token or the new one we generated at login
  $session = new FacebookSession( $session->getToken() );
}







if($display_login == 1){
//Display the login URL for the app. To do this, we must first -obtain- the login URL for the app, since the app is not actually accessible to the user.



echo "<a href=\"";
loginurl(); //This is a function in OtherScript.php, which simply outputs the login URL.
echo "\">Login</a>";

}else if($display_logout == 1){
  $request = new FacebookRequest( $session, 'GET', '/me' );
  $response = $request->execute();
  // get response
  $GraphObject = $response->getGraphObject(GraphUser::className());

  // print profile data
  $name = $GraphObject->getName();
  if($GraphObject->getID() == xxxxxxxxxxxx){ //Makes sure I'm the only one logged in (currently I'm the only person allowed to use the app, and I haven't started working on a database for authorized users just yet).
echo 'You are logged in, ' . $name . '.';
if(isset($_POST['thetextbox'])){


echo"<br>Your request is being evaluated. Please visit this page to see the progress on your request. *URL TO USER FILE GOES HERE*";

shell_exec('php ThirdScript.php token="' . $session->getToken() . '" text="' . $_POST['thetextbox']); //Clumsy way of handing the data off to a separate process/script. Ideally, this shell command will spawn a new process, that evaluates and thus writes to file all the data the user wants, using $session and all other data passed via $_GET through the shell.


}
echo'<p><form method="POST" action="">
  Enter Random Crap Here: <input type="text" name="thetextbox"> <br>
 <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
  </p>';
}else{
echo "You are not authorized to use this app, $name.";
  }
  }


echo '

</body>
</html>

';



?>
```

Otherscript.php:

```
<?php

require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookSession.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookRedirectLoginHelper.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookRequest.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookResponse.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookSDKException.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookRequestException.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookServerException.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookOtherException.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookAuthorizationException.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/GraphObject.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/GraphSessionInfo.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/GraphUser.php' );

use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\FacebookResponse;
use Facebook\FacebookSDKException;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
use Facebook\FacebookServerException;
use Facebook\FacebookOtherException;
use Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException;
use Facebook\GraphObject;
use Facebook\GraphSessionInfo;
use Facebook\GraphUser;



  // start session
session_start();

// init app with app id and secret
FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication( 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx','xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' );

// login helper with redirect_uri
$helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper( 'http://google.com' );
function loginurl() {
global $helper;
  echo $helper->getLoginUrl( array( 'email' ) );
}







function evaluate($token, $text){
//Do stuff! The actual app does some stuff and then writes to a file. When I run ThirdScript.php from the command line, I see the file being written to, and it works -perfectly-. When I run it from a browser via MainScript.php (which is the only way to run these from a browser, so that MainScript.php is the front end), it has a parse error and stops running, and nothing is written to the file.
}
?>
```

Thirdscript.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once ('otherevent.php');
if(isset($_GET["text"]) && isset($_GET['token'])){
evaluate($_GET['token'], $_GET['text']);
}
?>
```

Comment: You're running this with PHP < 5.3 then.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I am not, I have run php_info multiple times on the server this is running on. It's 5.4 actually. If it's lying to me, or something, how do I know/how can I change it?

Comment: So, when you run `php -v` on the command line it tells you 5.4? And that's the same php that you're using to run your script?

Comment: Yes, it says php 5.4.29, and it's the same php version used to run the script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING or '(' in ...

This happens when the interpreter doesn't understand namespaces entirely, i.e. a version of PHP is used that's lower than 5.3.

See also [this 3v4l](http://3v4l.org/2epHV) which emits the same parse error for those versions.

Comment: Then why is the command line, and php_info, saying it's 5.4.29 version?

Comment: That's the right question to ask :) but it's definitely not because of conflicting `use` statements because those are script-local and don't cause those parse errors. @Codefun64

Comment: I'm looking through some google searches about why php would report the wrong version, but I can't find much. Is this a server config issue of some kind?

Comment: @Codefun64 It could be something related to the path setting when used inside `shell_exec()` though; especially if there are multiple versions of php installed it may get the wrong one.

Comment: I've tried again running on the command line directly, in the public_html folder where the scripts are running normally, so that I bypass ever having to use MainScript.php; and it works just fine. So yeah, something's up with `shell_exec()`, but I don't know what... Any ideas? I've tried switching the php version a couple times to different variations of 5.4, I use bluehost, so I tried fastCGI, single .ini, and the regular php 5.4 version, and none of them actually work. But it still works fine from the command line directly.
So confused :/

Comment: @Codefun64 You could do `which php` on the command line and then use the absolute path to the interpreter.

Comment: I actually tried that just before you commented on that. That resulted in my script hanging up and not doing -anything-, oddly enough. Will try again.
EDIT: Again, MainScript.php hung up. However, it didn't appear to give the same error, it simply got caught in some kind of loop somewhere; MainScript.php was continually loading and nothing was outputting.

Comment: @Codefun64 So, I suppose that answers the question then? :)

Comment: I am using `PHP Version 5.5.3` on exampp 1.8 but still getting this error.